# Unable to update Nuget Package for JQuery

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, visual-sourcesafe

I have a project in VS 2010 and using Visual Source Safe 2005 for source control system. Whenever I try to update my NuGet Package. It shows "Installed" but, there are a lot of red color lines that appear and go as Nuget is isntalling packages.

I assume the installation is not correct for this. Can anybody help on this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the package first and then install it again? Or Force Package Update  (since NuGet 2.1)?

Comment: Force Package Update? I have not tried to uninstall and then install BTW...

Comment: can you paste the text from the red color lines?

Comment: @Betty Added the screenshot above, but it passes too quickly and after that it mentions success, which I doubt seriously...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's failing to uninstall a previous version of jquery ui because it has been modified from the original.

<strike>Try manually delete all the jquery files and remove the package node from the packages.config in the project file.</strike>

Because you want to keep your custom jquery ui, but appear to either upgrading all packages or  upgrading a package with a dependency on a newer version of jquery you are getting these errors.

If you are just trying to update all packages, and don't have any that rely on jquery ui I would remove it from the packages.config.  The files will still be there but no longer managed by NuGet.

If you are trying to upgrade a specific package that has a higher jquery ui dependency, then you can fake that the higher version is installed by editing the config, however the dependency is probably there for a reason and I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: I cannot remove the existing JQuery files. This is a big web application with more than 500 web forms and user controls. If I remove the existing JQuery (that are modified as well), it might result in some problem...

Comment: So you're not trying to upgrade jquery but install/upgrade another library that relies on an updated version of jquery then?  What package are you trying to install? and what version of jQuery do you currently have?